# dynamic add view at the beginning in a scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a linearlayout(fill with buttons) in horizontal scrollview. in runtime, it will load new data and add views from the beginning of the linearlayout. before adding views, for example, scrollx is 1000, and button A is displayed. but after adding views, scrollx remains 1000 but it displayed some new added button instread of button A. 
What I hope is, after adding, the current display doesn't change. Only when I move left I can see the new added views.

Anyone can provide some help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a specific width of the new button (or measure it by overriding onMeasure on a custom Button). Then manually scroll to 1000+newWidth.

Beware that the manual scroll should probably happen after views have been drawn, so posting it as a runnable on the UI thread should work.

Comment: thanks. But manual scroll to 1000+newWidth will cause a obvious scroll on the displayed, it's not friendly for user experience.

Comment: I think if you post the runnable HorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(x,0) at same time as adding button, they should both happen at the same time. If you get the measurements right (use HorizontalScrollView.getScrollX() to get the 1000), the user shouldn't notice anything.

Comment: I followed your solution and tried a simple example, it will still cause a quick flash.

Comment: It is possible the quick flash is caused by the relayout-ing of the views caused by adding views to the left. If you know the maximum number of buttons you are dynamically adding to the left, add them from time=0, and scrollTo the right, then just modify button parameters dynamically, but not size or position parameters that cause a relayout.